# Sum Values Of Field, Update Value In Other Field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL table similar to the below:

```
Mon.  Tues.  Wed.  Thur.  Friday.  Sat.  Sun.  TotalHours
1       3     4     3      6       NULL     8      NULL
4       NULL  3     4      5        0     0      NULL
```

I am trying to correct the **TotalHours** value for each record by summing the values of remaining "Day" columns.

I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Timekeeping]
SET [TotalHours] = [Sunday] + Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday + THursday + Friday + Saturday
WHERE [TotalHours] is null
GO
```

And the query does not error, and returns the amount of affected rows, however the change to the Hours value never changes. Is this because of some of the records having null values?

Comment: Use `ISNULL(Monday,0)+ISNULL(Tuesday,0)+....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this because of some of the records having null values?

Yes.

use `isnull` function, because null+value is null:

```
UPDATE [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Timekeeping]
SET [TotalHours] = isnull([Sunday],0) + isnull(Monday,0) + isnull(Tuesday,0) + isnull(Wednesday,0) + isnull(THursday,0) + isnull(Friday,0) + isnull(Saturday,0)
WHERE [TotalHours] is null
```